# How can I quit sqlite from a command batch file?

Tags: sqlite

I am trying to create a sealed command for my build pipeline which inserts data and quits.

So far I have created my data files

`things-to-import-001.sql` and `002` etc, which contains all the `INSERT` statements I'd like to run, with a file per table.

I have created a command file to run them

```sql
-- import-all.sql
.read ./things-to-import-001.sql
.read ./things-to-import-002.sql
.quit
```

However when I run my command

```
sqlite3 -init ./import-all.sql ./database.sqlite
```

..the data is inserted, but the program remains running and shows the `sqlite>` prompt, despite the `.quit` command. I have also tried using `.exit 0`.

From the `sqlite3 --help`

```
 -init FILENAME       read/process named file
```

Docs: https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html#reading_sql_from_a_file

How can I tell sqlite to exit once my inserts have finished?

Comment: Not sure why it does not work, but `sqlite3 -init commands.sql  something.db ".quit"` maybe?

Comment: I came across this which refers... https://sqlite.org/forum/info/4babe5d279078f95

Comment: I will experiment with a bash script instead I guess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to find a dirty workaround for this issue.

I have updated my import file to include a bad command, and executed using `-bail` to quit on first error.

```sql
-- import-all.sql
.read ./things-to-import-001.sql
.read ./things-to-import-002.sql
.fakeErrorToQuitWithBail
```

Then you can execute with

`sqlite3 -init import-all.sql -bail`

and it should quit with

`Error: unknown command or invalid arguments:  "fakeErrorToQuitWithBail". Enter ".help" for help`

Answer (score 0):

Try using ".exit" at the place of ".quit". For some reason SQLite dont doccumented this commands.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_commands.htm